# Drush Make: error "unable to unzip"

Tags: drush

I'm trying to setup a new project using the Drush `make` command. I'm working on localhost (xampp) on a Windows 8.1 machine.

The problem is that if a module present in my make file requires an external library (e.g. colorbox or plupload), `make` will detect that and will download said dependency, but then will **fail** to decompress it, resulting in the following error:

```
plupload-7.x-1.7 downloaded.                                                [ok]
Found makefile: plupload.make                                               [ok]
plupload downloaded from                                                    [ok]
https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/archive/v1.5.8.zip.
Unable to unzip                                                          [error]
```

As a result, the whole `make` operation is aborted.

I searched for a solution and found [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15889466/357546) answer that seems to address my problem but is not very detailed. I tried using Cygwin (x64), found an "unizp" package in it, tried to download it and copy the unzip.exe file in the `Program Files (x86)\Drush\GnuWin32\bin` folder, but now when I run my `make` project I have a new error message, this time as a dialog box (not in the console, then):

```
The program can't start because cygbz2-1.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.
```

Followed by a `unzip.exe has stopped working` Windows dialog box.

I can find the missing DLL (cygbz2-1.dll) in the `C:\cygwin64\bin` directory. So I tried adding this path to my PATH environment variable (and restarted my computer to be sure), but I still have the same "missing DLL" error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong 
(I'm not familiar with cygwin at all, so I don't know if I'm using it right...)?

Answer (score 1):

Get unzip for windows:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm
It solved the "unable to unzip" problem for me.